# Proving continuity for composed homotopy

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose $F$ and $G$ are homotopies between $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$, respectively. How to conveniently show that $$H(x,t)=G(F(x,t),t)$$
is continuous? I know how to do this recursing back to basic definitions like product topology and show that open map pulls back to open map...but what is the easiest way to compose some continuous functions to show the continuity of $H$?

Comment: I know this is quite a dumb question...but I'm just kind of mentally stuck somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the homotopies $F : X \times I \to Y$ and $g : Y \times I \to Z$, define $\hat F :  X \times I \to Y \times I, \hat F(x,t) = (F(x,t),t)$. This is a continuous map since both coordinate functions (these are $F$ and the projection $p : X \times I \to I$) are continuous. Thus the composition $H  = G \circ \hat F : X \times I \to Z$ is continuous.

Comment: For the statement that F hat is continuous because both coordinate functions are continuous, I’m not sure if we can prove this without using def of product topology using union of open sets. Can we prove that F hat is continuous by saying that the imbedding of F(x,t) in YxI is continuous?

Comment: Without using the product topology we cannot prove the continuity of $H$ or  of $\hat F$. But why do you want to avoid this? The product topology on $A \times B$ is *constructed* as the coarsest topology such that both projections $p_A : A \times B \to A$ and $p_B :  A \times B \to B$ become continuous. As a consequence a function $f : Z \to A \times B$ is continuous iff both $p_A \circ f$ and $p_B \circ f$ are continuous (*coordinatewise continuity*).

Comment: Ah because I felt that composing continuous functions is much neater than arguing about open and closed sets..so I’d like to see if we can just totally avoid talking about product topology.